# Prime ideals equivalence

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals, noncommutative-algebra

I'm reading Herstein's Non-commutative Rings book. His definition of prime ring is

> A ring $R$ is said to be a prime ring if $aAb=(0)$ then either $a=0$ or $b=0$.

Then he presents the following Lemma:

> A ring $R$ is prime if and only if:
>
> 1. the right annihilator of a nonzero right ideal of $R$ must be $(0)$.
> 2. the left anninhilator of a nonzero left ideal of $R$ must be $(0)$.
> 3. if $A$, $B$ are ideals of $R$ and $AB=(0)$ then either $A=(0)$ or $B=(0)$.

I can prove that if $R$ is prime then (3) is true. Moreover, it's easy to see that (3) implies (1) and (2). **I would like to prove that (1) or (2)  implies that $R$ is prime.** That's my attempt:

Suppose that (1) is true.
Let $a,b \in R$ such that $aAb=(0)$. Assume that $a\not=0$. We know that $aA$ is a right ideal and $b$ belongs to the right annihilator of $aA$. If $aA\not=(0)$ then $b$ must be equal to $0$. But how can I show that $aA\not=0$? Is it even true for the case without unit in $R$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's also easy to see that $1$ or $2$ implies $3$, so we can consider all three equivalent and compare them to the initial definition of prime.

Suppose $A$ is a rng satisfying (any, hence all of) $1,2,3$, and that $aAb=\{0\}$.  We aim to show either $a=0$ or $b=0$.

If $a=0$ we are done, so we consider when $a\neq 0$. By virtue of $1$, it must be that the right ideal $aA\neq \{0\}$.  By virtue of $2$, $(aA)b=\{0\}$ implies $b=0$.

Comment: I can't see clearly that $aA\not=(0)$. Why does it happen?

Comment: @GuilhermeCosta $A$ is a nonzero left ideal of $A$... since we have supposed 1) holds, nothing nonzero annihilates it on the left.

Comment: Now I see it! Thank you!